# PHP selecting multiple items from same colums to render in page

Tags: php, mysql

I guys I am having a bit of an issue with this

I have a select statement which looks like this belows

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->bindParam('id',$id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($row) {];
        ?>  
<div>  <?echo $row['Name']; >? </div>
<div>  <?echo $row['Type']; >? </div>


$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE Username IN ('john', 
                                'sarah', 'james')");
        $stmt1->bindParam('id',$id);
        $stmt1->execute();
        $row1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($row1) {];
            ?>  
    <div>  <?echo $row1['username']; ?>' </div>

      <? } ?> //closing for the second select statement 

<? } ?>  //closing for the first select statement
```

**The problem**

The page render but where I have use `SELECT * FROM user WHERE Username IN ('john', 
                                    'sarah', 'james')` it is only showing one name instead of 3 names.

I know the select statement works because I try it in phpmyadmin and it does show all 3 names

Comment: Why this $stmt1->bindParam('id',$id);?Where does it bind the param?In the second SELECT.

Comment: @Mihai I have it because I am recommendation an item based on what the user is viewing. I didnt really need it, thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
while($row1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>  
<div><?php echo $row1['username']; ?> </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Also remove `$stmt1->bindParam('id',$id);`

Because `if($row1)` only reads first row, you need to loop through the output by calling `$stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` each time for retrieving rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Instead of if($row1) use while($row1)

With if the loop only runs once but with while it runs as long there are results to loop through.